# Using conditionals in a Git alias?

Tags: linux, git

I want to add a confirmation before my Git aliases, e.g.:

```
amend = !echo -n 'Confirm: ' && read 'x' && [ $x == 'y' ] && git add -A && git commit -a --amend
```

This works directly in the terminal, but when I run it as a Git alias, I get:

```
echo -n 'Confirm: ' && read 'x' && [ $x == 'y' ] && git add -A && git commit -a --amend: 1: [: y: unexpected operator
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Can you paste what is written in your git config file for this alias ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am suspecting that git aliases use `sh` by default. Try replacing the `==` in your test command by `=`:

```
amend = !echo -n 'Confirm: ' && read 'x' && [ $x = 'y' ] && git add -A && git commit -a --amend
```

The `==` is defined by `bash`, but not by POSIX.
http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html